# Chern Class of a tensor product of coherent sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

If $\mathscr{E}$ is a vector bundle of rank $k$ and $\mathcal{L}$ is a line bundle, Then: $$c_{k}(\mathscr{E} \otimes \mathcal{L}) = \displaystyle \sum_{i = 0}^{k}\binom{r-l}{k-l}c_{1}(\mathcal{l})^{k-l}c_{l}(\mathscr{E})$$ Is there a similar result for the tensor product of coherent sheaves?

For example, if $r_{1} = \mbox{rank}(E)$ and $r_{2} = \mbox{rank}(F)$, then: $$c_{1}(E \otimes F) = r_{2}c_{1}(E) + r_{1}c_{1}(F)$$ $$c_{2}(E \otimes F)?$$ $$\cdots$$ $$c_{k}(E \otimes F)?$$ where $E$ and $F$ are coherent sheaves (we can assume them in a smooth projective variety of dimension $n$).

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your definition of the rank of a coherent sheaf?

Comment: Good quaestion, @Ruben du Burck. I'm a beginner in Algebraic Geometry. If an $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-module $\mathscr{F}$ is ismorphic to $\mathcal{O}_{X}^{n}$ as $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-modules, $\mathscr{F}$ is said to be a free module of rank $n$.

Comment: That is a definition on locally free sheaves. Locally free sheaves are coherent, but not all coherent sheaves are locally free.

Comment: @Ruben. What is the correct definition of the rank of a coherent sheaf? Thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a "correct" definition. In certain cases a coherent sheaf $\mathcal F$ will admit a finite locally free resolution $\mathcal E_\bullet \to \mathcal F$. In that case you can define $\text{rank}\; \mathcal F = \sum_i (-1)^i \text{rank}\; \mathcal E_i$. Of course this requires proving that this is independent of the choice of resolution.

Comment: @Ruben. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can find a formula for the first three Chern classes of a tensor product of locally free sheaves in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2890484/39599).

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much, Michael Albanese.